# Can I inject globals into a Node module before it's loaded?

Tags: unit-testing, node.js, knockout.js

I'm writing an app that's destined for the browser, and I want to write automated tests for my library code. I'd like to run those tests outside the browser, in a command-line environment like [Node](http://nodejs.org/). I haven't yet selected a test framework, though I'm leaning toward a BDD framework like [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/) or [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/).

My code depends on [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/)'s observable properties. Unfortunately, the Knockout library contains not just observable properties, but also code for binding them to the DOM. So if I just try to `require()` the Knockout library from Node, I get errors because the library is trying to reference the `window`, `navigator`, and `document` variables that are undefined in Node. Knockout actually doesn't use any of these variables *much* -- it's mostly just a bit of feature detection for the DOM bindings, which don't matter to me -- but because it does use them, Node won't even load the file.

So here's my question: **can I inject dummy variables into the module as it loads?** Could I do something to say "after you've loaded the source file, but before you've started running it, let me set a few variables inside the module so the code will run successfully"?

I know [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) already patches Node's module loader so it can load `.coffee` files in addition to `.js`; so it seems like there might also be some way to patch it to inject variables, if I only knew how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, yes you can -- create them and then use them, globals have no isolation.

Or, you might want to wrap a shim around the code textually, providing them inside a closure. jsdom does things like this to run jQuery. (And it provides a real DOM for that!)

Comment: D'oh! You're right, in JavaScript I can just do stuff like `window={};` before I call `require()` on Knockout. But I'm using CoffeeScript, which by default wraps everything in an anonymous function so globals don't bleed all over everything, so I have to set `global.window` instead. Once I knew there was something to look for, it wasn't hard to find -- thanks for pointing me in the right direction. (And thanks for pointing out jsdom -- that might help me out too!)

Answer (score 0):

Node.js isn't a "headless" environment in the sense it's commonly used (a headless *browser*).

jsdom can take you further along, but you should look into [PhantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org/), which is headless webkit, with DOM and all, and should fit your use case perfectly.

Comment: I have looked at PhantomJS a bit, but its test-runner support seems clunky (DOM scraping), and since tests are referenced by a `<script>` tag there's no great way to write tests in CoffeeScript. So I wanted to dig into Node and see how it stacked up.

Comment: And thanks for the correction on terminology. I've edited my post to remove the word "headless" since it doesn't mean what I thought it did.

Comment: coffeescript runs fine in Phantom with the `<script type="text/coffeescript">` method, you can also compile the files before running. What do you mean about DOM scraping? It's just like running the test suite on a browser

Comment: You've used `<script type="text/coffeescript">` with external scripts (`<script src="..."`)? The CoffeeScript site seems pretty clear that it's only for inline scripts. As to your question about DOM scraping, Phantom's Jasmine runner (examples/run-jasmine.js) repeatedly polls DOM elements until it sees a test result show up in one of them, and then it has to traverse the DOM to display the test results to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using felixge's node [sandboxed-module](https://github.com/felixge/node-sandboxed-module), you can sandbox the knockout library and inject globals into the sandboxed module.

From the readme:

```
var SandboxedModule = require('sandboxed-module');
var user = SandboxedModule.require('./user', {
  requires: {'mysql': {fake: 'mysql module'}},
  globals: {myGlobal: 'variable'},
  locals: {myLocal: 'other variable'},
});
```